# MongoDB: Aggregating hourly data into daily aggregates

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

I am collecting hourly crypto data. Each document is an array of objects. Within each of these objects there is another nested array of objects. It looks as follows:

```
timestamp: "2022-05-11T12:38:01.537Z",
positions: [
    {
        detail: 1,
        name: "name",
        importantNumber: 0,
        arrayOfTokens: [
            {
                tokenName: "name",
                tokenSymbol: "symbol",
                tokenPrice: 1,
                tokensEarned: 10,
                baseAssetValueOfTokensEarned: 10,
            },
            {
                tokenName: "name2",
                tokenSymbol: "symbol2",
                tokenPrice: 2,
                tokensEarned: 10,
                baseAssetValueOfTokensEarned: 20,
            },
        ],
    },
],};
```

My goal is to be able to aggregate the hourly data into daily groups, where the timestamp becomes the day's date, the position array still houses the primary details of each position, sums the importantNumber (these I believe I have been able to achieve), and aggregates each hour's token details into one object for each token, calculating the average token price, the total tokens earned etc.

What I have so far is:

```
    const res = await Name.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$positions",
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                timestamp: "$timestamp",
                detail: "$positions.detail",
                name: "$positions.name",
                importantNumber: "$positions.importantNumber",
                arrayOfTokens: "$positions.arrayOfTokens ",
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp" } },
                    name: "$name",
                },
                importantNumber: { $sum: "$importantNumber" },
                arrayOfTokens: { $push: "$arrayOfTokens" }, // it is here that I am stuck
            },
        },
    ]);

    return res;
};
```

With two hours recorded, the above query returns the following result, with the arrayOfTokens housing multiple arrays:

```
{
  _id: {
    date: '2022-05-11',
    name: 'name',
  },
  importantNumber: //sum of important number,
  arrayOfTokens: [
    [ [Object], [Object] ], // hour 1: token1, token2.
    [ [Object], [Object] ] // hour 2: token1, token2
  ]
}
```

I would like the arrayOfTokens to house only one instance of each token object. Something similar to the following:

```
...
arrayOfTokens: [
    {allToken1}, {allToken2} // with the name and symbol preserved, and average of the token price, sum of tokens earned and sum of base asset value.
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample desired output? This `importantNumber: { $sum: "$tvl" }` does not make much sense, because field `tvl` does not exist anywhere. `rewardTokens`  does not exist either.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply - please excuse the mistake. I edited out quite a lot of sensitive data before posting and clearly didn't do a good job. I have made your suggested edits, I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$positions" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$timestamp", unit: "day" } },
        name: "$positions.name"
      },
      importantNumber: { $sum: "$positions.importantNumber" },
      arrayOfTokens: { $push: "$positions.arrayOfTokens" }
    }
  }
])
```

I prefer `$dateTrunc` over group by string.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PzlQfgXiRiJ)

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to reply! This is certainly much cleaner than my approach, and I've token your note on board re `$dateTrunc`, that's really helpful.

The result of this places multiple arrays inside the array of tokens, which is what I was struggling with before. I have tried a second `$unwind` stage before grouping, but then the `$sum` of importantNumber is not correct.

Comment: It is very likely that having multiple arrays inside the arrayOfTokens is totally acceptable, and then it's a knowledge gap on my part regarding working with those nested arrays once the data has been queried to produce one object per token, summing together the necessary fields.

Comment: Just a note, you can aggregate also on array directly, for example `{ $set: { importantNumber_Average : {$avg: "$positions.importantNumber"} }`, i.e. you don't need `$unwind` and `$group` stage. Not fully clear, if you can use this for your data.

Comment: Oh that's a really helpful note! Thank you! I'll be sure to see if I can implement that.